# ggplot - Proportional stacked area plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I don't understand why I'm not getting my proportional stacked area graph to work. When I use the following code, I get this weird skewed visual:

```
ViolentCrimes <- ddply(ViolentCrimes, "Year", transform, PercentofTotal = Number_of_Crimes/sum(Number_of_Crimes) * 100)

ggplot(ViolentCrimes, (aes(x = Year, y = PercentofTotal, fill = Crime_Type)) +
  geom_area() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  ylab("Percent of Total")`
```

[image: Proportional Stacked Area Graph Fail]

But when I change geom_area to geom_bar, and add stat="identity", the bar graph seems to work just fine, even though it's hard to read (which is why I wanted the proportional area graph):

[image: Stacked Bar Plot]

Link to full data-set:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Be4rhySLUGUXkNke8zirwxVpKCZw3uSmW4Hkku0Uc9E/edit?usp=sharing

Any help is appreciated - thank you very much.

Comment: It's best if you provide your data using `dput` so that people can copy it directly.

Comment: My bad, first-time question asker... dput was messy, so I included a link to the full data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to prepare your data, grouping by Year and Crime_type. I use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
ViolentCrimes <- df  %>%
  group_by(Year, Crime_Type) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(Number_of_Crimes)) %>%
  mutate(percentage = n / sum(n))

ggplot(ViolentCrimes, (aes(x = Year,  y = percentage, fill = Crime_Type))) +
  geom_area()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I need to get better at piping. This is very helpful.

Comment: @LantzMcGinnis-Brown Glad to help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A slight improvement to the answer can be making ggplot do the heavylifting of converting y axis to percentage instead. This can be done done by adding `position = fill` argument to `geom_area()`

```
ViolentCrimes <- df  %>%
    group_by(Year, Crime_Type) %>%
    summarise(n = sum(Number_of_Crimes))

ggplot(ViolentCrimes, (aes(x = Year,  y = n, fill = Crime_Type))) +
    geom_area(position = "fill") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```